# If destructure preventDefault - with babel in react - this is undefined

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I just had the craziest bug. In my `onKeyDown` I destructred the `preventDefault` out of `e`. However when I would call `preventDefault()` I would get:

> TypeError: this is undefined[Learn More]react-dom.js:13987:5

I am using React v15.4.1 and the line is highlighted in my screenshot below:

[image]

If I don't destructure and just use `e.preventDefaut()` it works. Does anyone know why this is? Is this a bug in babel?

```
const El = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'El',
  onKeyDown(e) {
    let { key, preventDefault } = e;
    preventDefault();
  },
  render() {
    return React.createElement('input', { onKeyDown:this.onKeyDown });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Implementation of `preventDefault` method depends on other properties of event object, which are referred by `this` (namely: `this.defaultPrevented` property). When you destructure it from `e`, you detach this function from the base `e` object, which means that you loose context `this`. `preventDefault` method requires to be properly called with correct `e` object context. You can confirm this by calling it with `event` context which you can do with `Function.prototype.call`:

```
onKeyDown(e) {
  let { key, preventDefault } = e;
  preventDefault.call(e);
},
```

I would not destructure `preventDefault`.

Comment: Ah so this is not a babel bug, this is just how destructuring works? It removes the `this`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with either babel or destructuring. Noone removes `this`, but context `this` depends on how you call function. When you deach function the object it looses reference to the base object and can't point to its properties anymore. This is how javascript works. I suggest to read this doc about `this` and context in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this